# How to retrieve text data from Text Widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, textview

I am a beginner in flutter, how do i get or retrieve data from text widget. I have done some practice for example

```
Text("18:00"),
var data=Text("18:00");
print(data);
```

At the end instead of getting "18:00" i am getting "Text("17:05")" at the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve data fom a Text widget,

```
var data=Text("18:00");
print(data.data);
```

This will give you the output "18:00" as per your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

define this

```
var data = "18:00";

Text("18:00"),

print(data);
```

Comment: `var data = "18:00";
Text(data),
print(data);` if i do something like this. But this does not help his problem. Question is why print showing 17:55

Comment: that's fine but when i tried this **var data = Text("18:00");** and then when i **print("${data}");** my output is **Text("18:00")**.

Answer (score 0):

what do you want to do? if you want to get an input from user you should use text field or forms by setting controller to it and get data from controller.

```
 final myController = TextEditingController();
    TextField(controller: myController),
     var data=mycontroller.getText();
```

or if you want just get the text of text widget just set that text to a variable then pass it to widget.

```
String data="18:00"
 Text(data);
```